# log4j pattern %X and what property to assign to it

Tags: log4j, pattern-layout

i am trying to use a log viewer (doesn't matter which one) to parse my log files.

my log4j pattern is this.

%p [%t] (%C{1}:%M():%L) %d{dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm:ss,SSS} S:%X{serviceType} N:%X{requestID}- %m%n

the log viewers (at least the open source ones) need you to implement a pattern so they will be able to read the file.

for example:
for the log4j pattern: %p [%t] (%C{1}:%M():%L) %d{dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm:ss,SSS} - %m%n

the log viewer pattern would be:
pattern= pattern=LEVEL [THREAD] (CLASS:METHOD():LINE) TIMESTAMP - MESSAGE

the example works well.

but i have not been able to parse the %X property in any way. i have seen there are property types NDC and PROP(key) but i seem to either miss use them or they are not related to the %X

so the question is how to implement the pattern so it will read the %X parameter.

thanks.

Comment: Can you see the value of key serviceType and requestID from the MDC in your normal log file?

Comment: yes. but it is not used always. the value is empty at some places.

Comment: ok, thats normal... now, i don't know what log viewer you use? Did you check if this log viewer support the %X to read the MDC key/Values

Comment: i am using otroslogviewer, its an open source.
from what i see it supports NDC, not MDC.
http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/wiki/Log4jPatternLayout

Comment: Gleeb, have you tried to use newest version of OtrosLogViewer?
Your pattern should looks like this:
pattern= pattern=LEVEL [THREAD] (CLASS:METHOD():LINE) TIMESTAMP S:PROP(ServiceType) N:PROP(ReqID)- MESSAGE

Comment: thanks for the replay. this still doesn't work, the pattern you mentioned does not compile unless changing the '(' and ')' to '{' and '}' after the PROP value.
i assume that your the owner of the application from the user name, if you would like, i could send you a log sample and the log4 file for you to analyze. tried with version 11.11.11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i think i see the problem.

Your application use the log4J MDC since it use the %X in the pattern layout.  Your log viewer seems to support only NDC.

log4j pattern layout for NDC is %x (lowercase).

If you have control on the application, you have to change MDC -> NDC and modifiy the log4j.xml to use %x instead of %X.  That may be a big task if the app is huge...

Another solution would be to find a log viewer that support MDC(%X)

I tried to look around for the PROP(key), but there is not much doc on it ;-(

Good luck

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work, MDC and MDC does not work the same way. its either to remove the use of MDC all together or find something else.
that problem is that i haven't found any open source log viewer that supports MDC.